# Simple tool to open a new window in popup for screenshots

Tags: javascript, popup

I know! I know! This isn't a programming question! I'm desperate and I don't know where to turn. I just need a way to open any link up in a window with no junk up top, like this.

[image]

I know the way to do it in javascript but it's not ideal. I just would love a field I can put a link and press "open".

Comment: What have you tried? If you edit the question with the problem, the solutions you've tried, and the problems you've run into, you'll get a better response.

Comment: I just wanted a tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [JavaScript - Popups](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html) useful.

To open a blank window, set the url in that function to `""`